# Is there any formula for $16x^2 - 8x + 1$ to $(4x-5)(4x+3)$?

Tags: functions

I need to turn this $16x^2 - 8x + 1$ to $(4x-5)(4x+3)$ and I completely lost my logic on this one.
When trying to get $D$ with $D=b^2-4ac$ formula, I get $D < 0$.
Can someone explain me how to get these $-5$ and $+3$. Should I do this in my mind or is there another formula for this?
Thank you.

Comment: NOTE: $16x^2 - 8x + 1\ne(4x-5)(4x+3)$

Comment: It was (1-4x)^2 - 16, but I turned it into 1 - 8x + 16x^2 - 16 and then to 16x^2 - 8x - 15. The answer should be (4x-5)(4x+3). Hmm.  :/

Comment: You could use the formula for the difference between two squares, i.e.: $(1-4x)^2-16=(1-4x)^2-4^2=(1-4x+4)(1-4x-4)=(5-4x)(-3-4x)=(4x-5)(4x+3)$

Comment: Thank you. Now it's clear for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: Completing the square you have

$$16\Big[x^2 - \frac{1}{2}x\Big]  +1  = 16\Big[\left(x - \frac{1}{4}\right)^2 - \frac{1}{16}\Big]  +1 = 16\left(x - \frac{1}{4}\right)^2 - 1  +1 = (4x - 1)^2$$

Now think of $(4x -1)^2 - 4^2$ and use $a^2-b^2 = (a - b)(a+b)$.

Answer (score 1):

$ D = (-8)^2 - 4 \cdot 16 = 0 $ and $16x^2 - 8x + 1 = (4x - 1)^2$

Comment: So, maybe there is a mistake in my book, which gives me a wrong answer. Or i am really doing something wrong.

Answer (score 0):

$(a-b)^2=a^2-2ab+b^2.~$ In our case, $16x^2-8x+1=(4x)^2-2\cdot4x+1^2=(4x-1)^2$.